# Crontab task "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed ... with error -600 for the file ..."

Tags: command-line, cron

I just moved to a new MacBook with El Capitan and trying to set up my crontab to do backup tasks.  Here is how I have it set up (via `crontab -e`)

```
40 7 * * * /Users/myusername/daily.sh "daily tasks run 7:40a"
```

Daily.sh looks like this

```
open -b com.apple.terminal ~/backupThing1.sh
open -b com.apple.terminal ~/dailyThing2.sh
```

I have it set up this way so I see the terminals come up and can respond to some inputs and password prompts.

Anyway, this task fails with the following messages:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app with error -600 for the file /Users/myusername/backupThing1.sh.
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app with error -600 for the file /Users/myusername/dailyThing1.sh.
```

I have verified that these scripts are owned by `myusername` and are executable.  What am I missing?

Comment: LSOpenURLsWithRole() always seems to be an execute permissions error - there are many similar questions on Ask Different - http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=LSOpenURLsWithRole%28%29

Comment: I posted an answer for the same problem but error is showing as -10810... perhaps the asme thing. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [API documentation: LSOpenURLsWithRole()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9750475/55075).

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306766/237) the error is because you are trying to run a GUI app when not logged in.

However in your case why are you using a GUI app (Terminal ) here.

Just call your scripts directly from the cron script.

e.g. daily.sh should be

```
#!/bin/bash
~/backupThing1.sh
~/dailyThing2.sh
```

Note that you might need to have absolute paths not ~ here as cron jobs do not have the same environment as when run in the terminal.

Comment: you can use $HOME in place of `~` in most contexts where `~` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this error

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810
```

if you try to run most open commands (including for Calendar, PhotoBooth, etc.) without a user being logged in via the actual GUI. If you're remote, attach using VNC and log in. Otherwise just log in using the regular OS X GUI (i.e., the login screen we humans use).