# Open GUI App after reboot with cron

Tags: catalina, ui, reboot, cron

I'm using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 and I'd like to open some apps after boot with a cron tab. I use the following cron tab:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /Users/x/script.sh
```

if I run the script, it works as I want to, but cron executions fails with the following error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file ...
```

because, as noted in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306766), GUI apps can't be run before an user is logged to the GUI. Is there anything I can do? I was thinking about the possibility of a keyword that ran after login, not after boot. How may I achieve this?

Comment: maybe look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Comment: Why use cron - use apps to open at login. Until you login you can't run GUI apps